# Extend highlighting of built in language as new user defined language in Notepad++

Tags: css, less, notepad++, syntax-highlighting

I am currently customizing the syntax highlighting of `.less` files in Notepad++. I know I can import a user made `.xml` file and modify it to match my color scheme but this doesn't allow me to get it looking how I would like.

Is there a way to extend the current definition for `.css` files and create a user defined language from that? I would like the `.less` file to appear exactly the same as a `.css` file but add in the highlighting for `.less` specific code.

Comment: have you seen http://lesscss.org/usage/#editors-and-plugins--notepad-6-x-npp- already?

Comment: @BassJobsen Yeah. I've tried those (what I'm currently using) and, while they do a decent job, they fail to match the CSS styles exactly which is what I would like.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995 You'll find the default NPP definition for CSS in its `langs.xml` file (search for `<Language name="css" ...`, basically it's the same format as you use for custom language files).

Comment: @seven-phases-max Doesn't seem to be the case for me. I have `langs.model.xml` but the code you suggest is not the same as the code in exported user styles so I'm not sure how I would use it.

Answer (score 1):

Better in SynWrite app you do it: call "Lexer library" dialog and choose any lexer. Then edit it. Or make copy.